# Group rows based on range python

Tags: python, rows

I have a large text file where I am trying to group the first column based on intervals of 200. In the example code below, the first four rows would be in a group, the next three rows in a different group, and the last row in a separate group. My thought is to group them based on a for loop with a condition that adds 200, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
000008  34.576  -87.234
000025  34.825  -87.935
000123  35.935  -86.344
000154  34.395  -86.903
000234  35.219  -86.945
000322  34.240  -86.527
000359  34.893  -87.573
000412  35.291  -87.392
```

Once I have them grouped, I would like to check to see if the last two columns are within a specified range.  If so, then write those rows to a new output file. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the value by 200 to get a key for `groupby`:

```
>>> rows = '''000008  34.576  -87.234
000025  34.825  -87.935
000123  35.935  -86.344
000154  34.395  -86.903
000234  35.219  -86.945
000322  34.240  -86.527
000359  34.893  -87.573
000412  35.291  -87.392'''.splitlines()

>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for _, group in groupby(rows, key=lambda row: int(row.split()[0]) // 200):
        print(list(group))

['000008  34.576  -87.234', '000025  34.825  -87.935', '000123  35.935  -86.344', '000154  34.395  -86.903']
['000234  35.219  -86.945', '000322  34.240  -86.527', '000359  34.893  -87.573']
['000412  35.291  -87.392']
```

If the number always has six digits, you can use `int(row[:6]) // 200` instead.

Comment: I haven't used groupby before, so how would you be able to access the second and third columns? I tried looking up some background information on the function but have yet to find anything accessing columns.

Comment: @V22 Inside my loop, `list(group)` gives you the list of lines in one group, as seen in the output on the bottom of my answer. Do you see the three groups? You can then do with each group's list of lines whatever you want, has nothing to do with `groupby` anymore, which was only used to achieve the grouping. To parse the "columns", you could just `.split()` each line and apply `int` or `float` to turn the strings into numbers.

Comment: I do get those three groups, however I keep getting " 'itertools._grouper' object has no attribute 'split' " when I try to implement the .split() command.

Comment: @V22 Well firstly that's because you're trying to use `group` instead of `list(group)`, aren't you? Secondly, are you trying to split the list instead of the list elements?